# Thunderbird mac always send return receipts even after i set "never send"

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird mac 17.0.7, it always send "return receipts" even I have set the "Never send a return receipt". It did act as expected, but i don't know when and why it become so.
    I have check the global setting and the account setting, it does be "Never send a return receipt".
    Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is Exchange, it's [a feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296568%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).